# How do you set APP_PLATFORM in Gradle NDK plug-in in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, gradle-experimental

I'm building an app with an NDK library using Android Studio 1.5.1 and the [Gradle experimental plugin 0.4.0](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental).

Even though the Gradle config is set as such (with `minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 18`), it seems like the NDK library is still compiled for `android-21`:

```
compileOptions.with {
    sourceCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig.with {
        applicationId = "net.pol_online.hyper"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 18  // Android 4.3 Jelly Bean
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23  // Android 6.0 Marshmallow
    }
}
```

Is it because `APP_PLATFORM` is not automatically set by the Gradle NDK support based on the min SDK version? If so how do you fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle: change NDK build target independent from the SDK build target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403772/gradle-change-ndk-build-target-independent-from-the-sdk-build-target)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set this:

```
android.ndk {
   platformVersion = "19"
}
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33982735/3115956 for details on this. (In practice, I think your library is built targeting `android-23`, which has the same effect as targeting `android-21` - `compileSdkVersion` is the one that affects it (for both the java and native code, unless the native one is overridden).